# How to redefine/mock a method in Go for test purposes?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go

I am creating tests for a Go library. And I'm catching an error:

> cannot assign to

I have the following code (https://play.golang.org/p/kf0gANb-p-):

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"

    "os/exec"
    "strconv"
    "strings"

)
const (
    CONSOLE         = "dialog"
    KDE             = "kdialog"
    GTK             = "gtkdialog"
    X               = "Xdialog"
    DIALOG_TEST_ENV = "test_env"
    AUTO            = "auto"
)

const (
    DIALOG_ERR_CANCEL = "exit status 1"
    DIALOG_ERR_HELP   = "exit status 2"
    DIALOG_ERR_EXTRA  = "exit status 3"
)
type Dialog struct {
    environment string
    parentId    int
    title       string
    backtitle   string
    label       string
    height      int
    width       int
    left        int
    top         int
    shadow      bool
    helpButton  bool
    helpLabel   string
    extraLabel  string
    cancelLabel string
    okLabel     string
    beforeDtype []string
    beforeSize  []string
    afterSize   []string
    lastCmd     []string
}

func (d *Dialog) Yesno() bool {
    if _, err := d.exec("yesno", true); err != nil {
        if err.Error() == DIALOG_ERR_CANCEL {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func NewTestDialogRAW(environment string, parentId int) Dialog {
    var res = new(Dialog)
    LastCMD = []string{}
    return *res
}
func (d *Dialog) exec(dType string, allowLabel bool) (string, error) {
    var arg string
    cmd := exec.Command(d.environment)

    if d.okLabel != "" {
        cmd.Args = append(cmd.Args, "--ok-label", d.okLabel)
    }
    if d.extraLabel != "" {
        cmd.Args = append(cmd.Args, "--extra-button")
        cmd.Args = append(cmd.Args, "--extra-label", d.extraLabel)
    }
    if d.helpButton {
        cmd.Args = append(cmd.Args, "--help-button")
        if d.helpLabel != "" {
            cmd.Args = append(cmd.Args, "--help-label", d.helpLabel)
        }
    }
    if d.shadow == false {
        cmd.Args = append(cmd.Args, "--no-shadow")
    }
    if d.backtitle != "" {
        cmd.Args = append(cmd.Args, "--backtitle", d.backtitle)
    }
    if d.cancelLabel != "" {
        cmd.Args = append(cmd.Args, "--cancel-label", d.cancelLabel)
    }
    if d.title != "" {
        cmd.Args = append(cmd.Args, "--title", d.title)
    }
    for _, arg := range d.beforeDtype {
        cmd.Args = append(cmd.Args, arg)
    }
    cmd.Args = append(cmd.Args, "--"+dType)

    if allowLabel == true {
        cmd.Args = append(cmd.Args, d.label)
    }
    for _, arg = range d.beforeSize {
        cmd.Args = append(cmd.Args, arg)
    }
    if d.environment != KDE {
        cmd.Args = append(cmd.Args, strconv.Itoa(d.height))
        cmd.Args = append(cmd.Args, strconv.Itoa(d.width))
    }
    for _, arg = range d.afterSize {
        cmd.Args = append(cmd.Args, arg)
    }
    if d.environment == CONSOLE {
        cmd.Args = append(cmd.Args, "--stdout")
    } else {
        cmd.Args = append(cmd.Args, "--attach")
        cmd.Args = append(cmd.Args, strconv.Itoa(d.parentId))
    }

    var out bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &out
    var err error
    if d.environment != DIALOG_TEST_ENV {
        err = cmd.Run()
    }
    d.lastCmd = cmd.Args

    //d.reset()
    return strings.Trim(out.String(), "\r\n "), err
}



func main() {
var tests = []bool{true, false}
for _,expected_val := range tests {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground ",expected_val )
    }
}
```

I tried to test it but I don't know how to redefine the method?

main_test.go:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)
func TestYesNo(t *testing.T) {
    d := NewTestDialogRAW(DIALOG_TEST_ENV, 0)
    d.Yesno()
    x := LastCMD
    expected_str := "[ --no-shadow --yesno  0 0 --attach 0]"
    if fmt.Sprintf("%v", x) != expected_str {
        t.Errorf("Expected %v, actual %v ", expected_str, x)
    }
    f := func(dType string, allowLabel bool) (string, error) {
        return "", fmt.Errorf(DIALOG_ERR_CANCEL)
    }
    d.exec = f    
}
```

go test ./... -v

```
# _/root/Development/git-repos/go-dialog
./dialog_test.go cannot assign to d.exec
FAIL    _/root/Development/git-repos/go-dialog [build failed]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d.exec` is not a part of struct declaration (it is not a struct field). It is a method defined on dialog type. Hence it is not addressable and cannot be assigned to.

You can try embedding `Dialog` in a new type and redefine `exec` on that type.

```
type TestDialog struct {
    Dialog
}

func (d *TestDialog) exec(dType string, allowLabel bool) (string, error) {
    return "", fmt.Errorf(DIALOG_ERR_CANCEL)
}
```

Comment: I added the 'NewTestDialogRAW' function in my example

Comment: I am using your workaround but func (d *Dialog) Yesno() bool { if _, err := d.exec("yesno", true) is using exec from Dialog, not from TestDialog

Comment: It appears you need to stub `Yesno`. Stubbing is hard in Go due to its static nature but if your test requires a certain return value from `Yesno`, the above work-around can be used, just define `Yesno` on `TestDialog` to return the error and remove `exec` since `Yesno` is what's calling `exec`. Otherwise you can also repeat `Yesno` on `TestDialog` along with `exec`. It's not the most ideal solution.Since `exec` depend on `cmd.Run()` in the end, perhaps a better solution would be to fake a `cmd` value. But that would come with its own complexity.